# Translating C to MIPS with a ternary operator

Tags: c, mips, translate

In my class we are translating C to MIPS.

We are asked to translate this snippet:
`A = A ? B : C[0]`

I believe I understand the ternary operator, but what is wanted here? Shouldn't A be a boolean? So would it be represented in MIPS with a 1 or 0 value?

Thank you

Comment: `A` should be an arithmetic or pointer type. In a Boolean context, `A` is evaluated as if by `A != 0`.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to translate the ternary expression to pseudo code first, e.g.:

```
if A != 0       // if A is non-zero, i.e. TRUE
    A = B
else            // otherwise A is zero, i.e. FALSE
    A = C[0]
```

Comment: That makes sense, but where did the zero come from?

Comment: In C a variable that is non-zero is defined to be `true`.