# What does & mean as a ternary operator

Tags: java, c++, ternary-operator

I have this piece of code I'm going to translate into mips but I don't know what it means: `A = B & C[0]`

When I google ternary operator I can't find any mention of the `&`, just `e1 ? e2 : e`

What does it mean?

Comment: Why do you think that's a *ternary* operator? If you think it is, do you also think `A = B + C[0]` is a ternary operator?

Comment: I suppose your teacher use a book with mistype - similar question was already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160408/translating-c-to-mips-with-a-ternary-operator

Comment: `&` is not a ternary operator in your example its a *binary* operator.

Comment: There are assembly languages in which `AND` is ternary (e.g. having two input registers and an output register). Higher-level programming languages don't work that way: the result is a _temporary_ and you need to decide what to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no ternary operator here. The expression is equivalent to `A = (B & C[0])`, that is `A` is assigned with the result of bitwise AND applied to `B` and `C[0]`.

Comment: ...or the logical AND if the variables are `boolean` types.

Answer (score 0):

```
 bitwise AND
```

Take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

And look here for an example
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm

Comment: It's bitwise AND in C++. In Java, it depends on the types of the operands; it could be either bitwise AND or the non-short-circuit logical AND.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` here is the binary (2 inputs) operator "bitwise and".
In this case you have:

```
A = B & C[0];
```

So `A` will receive the results of the bit-by-bit and-ing of `B` and `C[0]`.
Lets imagine that A, B and C[0] are two 32 bit integers, that have values I randomly assigned them, and lets view this operation in binary:

```
B    = 0000 0001 0010 0100 1000 1001 1011 1111
C[0] = 1001 1110 1101 1101 1010 1010 1010 0101
A    = 0000 0000 0000 0100 1000 1000 1010 0101 (the and of the two values above)
```

that is, `A` has a `1` bit only where both `B` and `C[0]` have `1` bits.

In decimal this is `19171775 & 2665327269 = 297125`.

BTW, a ternary operator has 3 inputs, most common being `?:`, as in `R = C ? B : A`.